# Strapi Cron doesn't work after migrating to version strapi-3.0.0

Tags: api, content-management-system, strapi

Cron usually worked in the strapi-3.0.0-beta.20 version
but It doesn't work after migrating to version strapi-3.0.0

**Strapi-3.0.0-beta.20**

`./config/environments/{env}/server.json`

```js
{
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 1337,
    "proxy": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "cron": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "admin": {
        "autoOpen": false
    }
}
```

**Strapi-3.0.0**

`./config/server.js`

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: env.int('PORT', '1337'),
    production: env('NODE_ENV') === 'production' ? true : false,
    proxy: {
        enabled: false
    },
    cron: {
        enabled: true
    },
    admin: {
        autoOpen: false
    }
})
```

This is strapi code that uses the server.js

[strapi/packages/strapi/lib/middlewares/cron/index.js](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/baf3891865cffa30ed9b44b110674690b3f515a8/packages/strapi/lib/middlewares/cron/index.js)

```js
  if (strapi.config.get('server.cron.enabled', false) === true) {
      _.forEach(_.keys(strapi.config.get('functions.cron', {})), task => {
          cron.scheduleJob(task, strapi.config.functions.cron[task]);
  });
```

Comment: Hey Lucas, update to 3.0.1 https://github.com/strapi/strapi/releases/tag/v3.0.1 there's a fix for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the content registered in the [github issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/6541).

**Describe the bug**
Incorrect information in documentation for new configuration loader

**Expected behavior**
There is a possibility of misunderstanding in the document regarding the cron setting.

This is a setting to activate cron (3.0.0.beta.20)
./config/environments/{env}/server.json

```
{
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 1337,
    "cron": {
        "enabled": true
    }
}
```

The documentation on how to migrate guides like this.
[Migrating](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-beta.20-to-3.0.0.html#migrating)

```
Server

Your server configuration can move from ./config/environments/{env}/server.json to 
./config/server.js like shown here.
```

[Server](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/configurations.html#server)
Available options -> cron

However, to enable cron in version 3.0.0  must do it in the middleware.js

./config/middleware.js

```
    timeout: 100,
    load: {
        before: ['responseTime', 'logger', 'cors', 'responses', 'gzip'],
        order: [
            "Define the middlewares' load order by putting their name in this array is the right order"
        ],
        after: ['parser', 'router']
    },
    settings: {
       ...
       cron: { enabled: true }
       ...
    }
```

**Code snippets**
After checking the code (strapi/middlewares/index.js), I learned that it should be set in middleware.

**System**
- Node.js version: v12.14.0
- NPM version: 6.13.6
- Strapi version: 3.0.0
- Database: mongodb
- Operating system: window, linux